# Existe alguma ferramenta que faça o processo inverso da modelagem?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, der

Sempre, ou quase, se é feito o ER Conceitual para depois modelarmos o ER Lógico, no [BR Modelo](http://www.sis4.com/brmodelo/download.aspx) é possível criar o ER Conceitual e gerar o ER Lógico automaticamente, porém quando há a necessidade de se fazer o processo inverso? como podemos fazer isso? Existe alguma ferramenta que faça esse processo?

Comment: Tem certeza que está usando os termos corretos? Não está querendo dizer modelo lógico e físico? https://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/data-modeling-levels.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Comment: Não achei nada nesse software que ele gere o modelo lógico partindo do conceitual, nem poderia, não tem como ele adivinhar. No máximo ele evita a repetição do que é igual nos dois. Não é possível gerar algo sem ter todas informações possíveis. O oposto é mais fácil. Este é um software obviamente acadêmico e limitado. Certamente vários outros software no mercado fazem isto. Mas não sei se é tão vantagem a diferença entre esses dois modelos é mínima e raramente uma mudança no lógica afetará o conceitual. Faz mais sentido do físico para o lógico. Isto normalmente se chama engenharia reversa.

Comment: @bigown, Sim são estes os modelos conceitual e logico, no BR modelo quando você cria um diagrama conceitual e clicar com o botao direito no menu que aparecer a primeira opção é gerar esquema lógico...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem diversas ferramentas bem mais completas, a maioria paga (mas tem grátis, mesmo que de código fechado). Todas que eu conheço fazem engenharia reversa do modelo físico para lógico e do lógico para o conceitual. O melhor ponto de partida é a [página da Wikipedia sobre isso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_modeling_tools).

Tem uma [lista mais completa](http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Do esquema Lógico no BR MODELO é possível gerar somente o Físico, que no BR MODELO é o código SQL. Este é um software particularmente acadêmico, não considero o software ideal para produção de modelagem de Banco de Dados.

Eu particulamente considero o WorkBench que é mais produtivo, eficaz e oferece ferramentas mais completas e profissionais.